# VSTS API - repository creation date

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I've checked VSTS REST API documentation, but I haven't found a method which allows me to get information about the repository creation date.

Is it possible to get such data via the VSTS API?

Comment: - you should also post the links of the standard docs, where you have looked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to get the exact date of the moment the operation `create repo` was completed. However, logically the birthday of the repository is usually considered its first commit date.

If that's what you're looking for, you can achieve your goal with a usual Git command:

```
git log -1 --reverse --format="format:%ci"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the first commit date for the repository. Check the [Get Commits API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/commits/get%20commits?view=vsts-rest-4.1):

```
GET https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/_apis/git/repositories/{project}/commits?api-version=4.1
```

Comment: Thank you. I decided for same approach but it is not perfect for me. In case of my company sometimes it takes a bit of time between repository creation and first commit. Sound weird but that's the case. I want to measure "process gap" between project setup in VSTS and start of real development activities but it seems that's not possible using VSTS API.

Comment: There is no history for an empty repo, so we can not get the creation time for a repo. I've submitted a UserVoice at website below, you can vote it: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/34687609-provide-vsts-rest-api-to-get-creation-time-of-a-re